# Android google maps cant zoom with compass active

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming

Hee guys,

I'm currently using a sensorlistener to make my screen adjust as a compass. However I can't zoom in or out because I am constantly updating the camera when `onSensorChanged` is called. Is there any way to make it able to zoom?

```
private SensorEventListener mySensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(routeStarted == true)
        {
            if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {
                SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(
                        mRotationMatrix , event.values);
                float[] orientation = new float[3];
                SensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, orientation);
                float bearing = (float) (Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]) + mDeclination);
                float tilt = 30;
                updateCamera(bearing, tilt);

            }
        }
    }
};  

private void updateCamera(float bearing, float tilt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LatLng post = new LatLng(mGoogleMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), mGoogleMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude());
        CameraPosition pos = new CameraPosition(post, 15, tilt, bearing);
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(pos));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the currentzoom level obtained from the map instead of the static value 15. like this:

```
float zoom = map.getCameraPosition().zoom;
CameraPosition pos = new CameraPosition(post, zoom, tilt, bearing);
```

If you want to initialise the view on 15, then do this somewhere else for example when the activity starts.

Comment: If this was the answer you were seeking, could you please mark it?

Comment: Works, however it isn't as smooth as normal. But that's because when you try to zoom, the sensorlistener is activated and will reload the camera. But it's good enough, thank you! And sorry was eating lunch so I was a little late with implementing.